# I need to connect MySql with my C # application for Windows CE, any idea about this error?

Tags: c#, mysql, windows

Basically, I need to connect an application for windows CE with a MySql database. The problem is that I wanted to use Mysql Connector and I'm not sure if that's the right way. Any suggestions to solve this problem or maybe go the other way.

I'm using:
Visual Studio 2008
Windows CE

`Error 1   The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.`

Comment: Add a Reference to System.Data - or atleast to that specific version. The error clearly tells what is wrong

Comment: hello @TobiasTheel, I'm already making that reference